# Black screen - random log out

Tags: suspend, login-screen, 17.10, logout

I've installed Ubuntu 17.10 on my new Dell XPS 13 (a machine dedicated for Linux) and I already experience some kind of trouble. Let me describe the situation:
I'm working, suspending the computer by closing the lid, continue working etc. The bug I'm experiencing occurs several times a day and somehow seems to be related to ALT + TAB, especially when switching to the pdf reader but only every third time or so. Ubuntu shows a black screen with one row of @@@@@@ and logs me out. I can then log in without any trouble but all my applications are of course closed. Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: I am also logged out when my pomodoro app goes for the first break, and when I try to add an app to favorites.

Comment: Same problem here, also on XPS13. I cannot confirm the ``<alt><tab>`` relation, though, I don't have any pdf viewer open.

Comment: I have the exact same problem - I was using nightlight when it happened. Turned that off and have not experienced the problem since. I will keep an eye on it and let you know if it happens again.

Comment: I have tried disabling all of the above cited functionality but still get 'random' logouts. Has anyone found a reliable fix for this? Or could recommend how to diagnose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the newest system update for XPS 13 fixed the problem. I haven't experienced it yet after updating.

Comment: Could you provide a link for the update?